# Get element with JQuery from complex html structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So... On click, I want the button with a class "**clicker**" to get, through JQuery, the element with the class "**popup-box**". The structure I have below appears several times throughout the page, and that's my problem... I want the "clicker" to target only the "popup-box" that comes after him.

My structure is as follows (this is repeated several times):

```
<div class="item-papers">
    <div class="img-wrap">
        <div class="img-innerwrap">
            <a href="#" class="clicker"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="floater">
        <span></span>
        <div class="item-papers-content">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <div class="popup-box"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've messed around with .sibblings(), .parents(), .find(), but I can't, for my life, figure out how to reach it.

Any help is really appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: `$(this).closest('.item-papers').find('.popup-box')` would get it inside `.clicker` click handler

Comment: Thank you very much, it's painfully simple! hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, their closest common parent is the `.item-papers` element.

So go upwards from the clicked element with `.closest('.item-papers')` and then downwards with `.find('.popup-box')` to get the popup element..

```
$('.clicker').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this),
        popup = self.closest('.item-papers').find('.popup-box');

    // do what you want with the popup element here..
});
```

Comment: Oh man it's so simple I'm ashamed... I blame tiredness heheh
Thank you sir!